# How to use entity field to select entity to edit

Tags: php, forms, symfony

A controller calls a form with an EntityType to select an entity to edit. The form's template does not return to the controller with the id of the entity.  Thought I knew how to do this but I've tried multiple variations without success. Current state:

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/edit/{id}", name="artist_edit")
 */
public function editArtistAction(Request $request, Defaults $defaults, $id = null)
{
    if (null !== $id) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $artist = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Artist')->find($id);
    } else {
        $form = $this->createForm(SelectArtistType::class, null, ['target' => 'edit']);

        return $this->render('Artist/selectArtist.html.twig',
                [
                'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
...
}
```

Form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $target = $options['target'];
    $builder
        ->add('artist', EntityType::class,
            [
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Artist',
                'label' => 'Select artist for ' . $target,
                'choice_label' => function($artist, $key, $index) {
                    return $artist->getLastName() . ', ' . $artist->getFirstName();
                },
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                        ->orderBy('a.firstName', 'ASC')
                        ->orderBy('a.lastName', 'ASC');
                },
        ])
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class,
            array(
                'label' => 'Select',
                'label_format' => ['class' => 'text-bold']
    ));
}
```

Template:

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
{% block body %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            {{ form_start(form) }}
            {{ form_row(form.artist) }}
            {{ form_rest(form) }}
            {{ form_row(form.save) }}
            {{ form_end(form) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock body %}
```

Comment: Not sure to understand the question tbh. I suggest you rephrase it a bit or explain what you want to do and what's not working.

Comment: Controller presents a form if an id is not provided. The form as a drop-down of artist names is presented by SelectArtistType. When the Select button is clicked, presumably submitting the form, it should POST an id to the controller so that the selected entity can be edited.  Instead the form remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're **not** reading the data coming from the POST anywhere. In your controller you should check the request when you receive a post. Put something like this at the beginning of the controller so you can see what you're receiving in the POST:

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    var_dump($request->request)
}
```

And then process it as you prefer getting the parameter you need.

Comment: Including `if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {dump($id);}` immediately after controller's `if () ...` statement does NOT dump an id.  So a test for POST does not help. In addition, the controller below the ellipsis (and not shown in the question) does include the standard `$form->handleRequest($request);` and `if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())...`

Comment: You should add it before everything else and `var_dump($artist)` o `var_dump($request->request)` in order to see what you get from the form.

Comment: Yikes! What I get when I `var_dump($request->request)` at the top of the controller is a ParameterBag with `... array(1) { ["select_artist"]=> array(3) { ["artist"]=> string(1) "1" [...`.  This I can deal with.  Thanks for the help.  I've not used this trick before and I doubt it will be the last. Edit your answer to show this and I'll accept it.  Thanks again.

Comment: As it turns out, this method of getting an entity to edit fails later in the controller.  The eventual solution was to build a switch statement inside the controller that presents the SelectArtist form. That form is used multiple times for different purposes.  This solution can be posted if requested.